# Is there a way to run nightwatch on Safari v12.1?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, nightwatch.js, safaridriver

My mac auto-updated safari to v12.1, but now I can't run my nightwatch tests against safari. I just always get the error: "Request body does not contain required parameter 'capabilities'.". I think it's related to this issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6431

Is there anything I can update or do inside of nightwatch to get the tests to run again?

Comment: Using the later comments from this github issue I got safari v12 opened and running tests: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/issues/94
BUT a lot of core nightwatch commands no longer work. So far I've found that waitForElementVisible(), moveTo(), and keys() do not work with that configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out safari made some huge breaking changes in v12. They removed support for the Selenium JSON wire protocol and now only support w3c WebDriver protocol. There isn't much you can do from a nightwatch config standpoint to fix this. Just try to find the w3c equivalent command for what you are trying to do and use that instead.
Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/macos_webdriver_commands_for_safari_12_and_later